# How do I use mailSettings\smtp with both the configSource and from attributes?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am trying to clean up our web.config file such that per-deployment specific stuff is not kept in the main config. I have managed with the connections strings and some of the `mailSettings`, but I need the `from` attribute as well as the `configSource`, but this doesn't seem to be allowed.

Currently I have this:

web.config:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings >
      <smtp configSource="email.config" from="me@blahblah.com" />
    </mailSettings>
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy bypassonlocal="True" usesystemdefault="False" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

email.config

```
<network host="myhost" password="" userName="" />
```

Ideally I would have the set the `configSource` on either `mailSettings` or `system.net`, but this isn't supported.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

OK, this is a missunderstanding on my part. I didn't think I could do:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings >
      <smtp configSource="email.config" />
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

and:

```
<smtp from="someone@stackoverflow.com">
    <network host="myhost" password="" userName="" />
</smtp>
```

Which you can. Hopefully me being daft in public will help someone else retain their dignity and not have to ask daft questions.

Comment: You helped me so at least it was worth something! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide: If you use configSource it wins and the other settings are ignored. What are your reasons for using both? If this is a Debug / Release issue you can use two different configSource files and copy them to the right places with an after build action.

Comment: The reason for needing both is simple, I want to use configSource, but I also want a default from address. It's an existing app and I'd rather not hack around trying to put the from address in everywhere.